# Проблема с циклом while в Python

Tags: python

Только начал изучать Питон, можете помочь?

```py
b = int(input("Введите число от 1 до 10: "))
a = random.randint(1,10)
print(b)
print(a)
if b == a:
    print('Угадал')
else:
    while a != b:
        if b > a:
            print("Много")
        elif b < a:
            print("Мало")
```

Как сделать так чтобы цикл остановился. Буду рад если поможете)

Comment: Для остановки цикла используется ключевое слово `break`.

Comment: Тут другая проблема. Зачем тут вообще этот цикл?

Answer (score 2):

вам совершенно не нужен `while`.  Вы можете просто сделать так:

```
else:
     if a > b:
        print('много')
     elif a < b:
        print('мало')
```

Answer (score 1):

А, все разобрался. Надо было использовать команду break

Answer (score 1):

```py
from random import randint

a = randint(1, 10)

while (b := int(input("Введите число от 1 до 10: "))) != a:

    if b == 0:
        print('Не угадал')
        break
    elif b not in range(1, 11):
        print(f'Число {b} вне диапазона')
        continue

    print('Много' if b > a else 'Мало')
else:
    print('Угадал')
```

Answer (score 0):

Как остановить цикл:

Для этого в питоне есть оператор **`break`**.
Когда ты пишешь в цикле эту команду, он немедленно прерывается.

Пример:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    ans = input()
    if ans == 'exit':
         break # немедленно прерываем цикл
    else:
        print(int(ans) ** 2)
    i += 1
```